# How does one "secure" a python CLI-based application?

Tags: licensing, python, python-3.x, cli

I have to provide a Python CLI-based program to one of my clients. I will give him both the compiled version (using py2exe or something simillar) of the application and the source code.

The application structure is the following:

- a *cfg* folder which holds some configuration files (the main `.py` parses these configs using `configparser` module and processes the data inside them
- a *log* folder which will hold the logging files generated by the app
- *in* / *out* folders which will be used for input / output files
- a *processed* folder which will hold the input files that were used.

Now, the client will give the `.exe` version of the app to some clients and he wants to make sure that the only person that will use the app will be the one he has handled it to.
Having said this, he asked for a way / hacky workaround of *protecting* the app in a way or another. He specified that he does not need a 100% way of protection (we all know that if there's a determined person in charge of this, he'll get around it anyways) but a decent one.

I know that Python, being a byte-code-compiled interpreted language, is very difficult to lock down. I'm not looking for a way to protect the code.I just need some kind of **license key system** embedded in my python code.

The question would be: **how would you secure your Python CLI-based application?**

Comment: @gnat it doesn't seem a duplicate to me. I asked for a way of securing my app in terms of limiting the user to spread up the program and use it on their own behalf (a _hacky_ way of some hidden file or so)

Comment: [top answer in the duplicate](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/10343/31260) explains that the way you want it won't work and what you really need instead. "If you want people to pay money for your product, copy protection is not the answer. It never has worked and never will. The answer lies in Economics 101: people will pay money for your product if..." etc

Comment: "limiting the user to spread up the program" sounds **very** much like "prevent piracy" to me. Clearly a dupe. This question or variants of it has been asked here and probably on SO several times.

Comment: There is no software solution.  Try something contractual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution. It does not protect the code and can be **easily** hacked, but nevertheless it requires some effort from customers who are breaking bad).

Instead of getting a generic executable, a customer will receive an executable with an embedded unique password, The password should be supplied to the program as a command-line argument:

```
program.exe pseudocode:

USER_KEY_PLACEHOLDER = '0000000000000000' # e.g. 16 chars

password = get_cli_argument('-p')

h_password = hash(password)
if h_password != USER_KEY_PLACEHOLDER:
    raise InvalidPassword()
```

The signer program should be supplied to your customer.

```
program_signer.exe pseudocode:

password = get_cli_agument_or_generate_random_string()
h_password = hash(password)

find_user_key_placeholder_in_program_exe()
embed_h_password_into_user_key_placeholder()
```

So, the whole supply chain goes as follows:

The customer has the **program** and the **signer**. Every time an end-user requests the program, the customer uses the **signer** as follows:

```
signed_program = signer(program, password)
```

A password - is a unique string, randomly generated for every user.

The end-user receives a **signed_program** and a personal unique **password**. The **signed_program** will start only if a correct password is supplied.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How will this stop the customer from giving the `program` + `program_signer` to other user ? Can you give me more details about how all the flow should work ?

Comment: I've just added more details. Please ask, if anything is requires more comments.

Comment: what would stop that user to give that specific program with the password embedded in it and the program to another user ?

Comment: Nothing. This solution is primitive and is not about copy protection.